# Boolean Take Profits in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, trading, algorithmic-trading

Im wanting to create a Take Profit parametre that exit a position when a certain condition is met, for example

Long_take_Profit = ta.crossunder(adx, plus)

any solutions on how to turn this condition in to its float counter part or alternativley just use the condition itself.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to close your position conditionally, you should use `strategy.close()`.

If you additionally want to check if you are in profit, you can use the `strategy.opentrades.profit` built-in variable.

```
is_in_profit = (strategy.opentrades.profit(strategy.opentrades - 1)) > 0

if (Long_take_Profit and is_in_profit)
    strategy.close("Long")
```

Answer (score 0):

TP (or [limit](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dexit)) is usually a line that the price must cross
But in this case (ADX cross DI), just use the condition itself.

```
if strategy.position_size > 0 and Long_take_Profit 
    strategy.exit(
      id             = 'Long Exit',
      from_entry     = 'Long Entry')
```

Comment: strategy.exit() requires at least one of the following parameters: 'profit', 'limit', 'loss', 'stop' or one of the following pairs: 'trail_offset' and 'trail_price' / 'trail_points'